# Save generated image file as a Paperclip attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, minimagick

I have a method which is generating QR code for some string using `rqrcode-rails3` gem:

```
def generate_qrcode(string, options={})
  format = options[:format] || :png
  size   = options[:size]   || RQRCode.minimum_qr_size_from_string(string)
  level  = options[:level]  || :h

  qrcode = RQRCode::QRCode.new(string, size: size, level: level)
  svg    = RQRCode::Renderers::SVG::render(qrcode, options)

  image = MiniMagick::Image.read(svg) { |i| i.format "svg" }
  image.format "png" if format == :png
  image
end
```

That newly generated image would be attached to the model object and stored in the database using `paperclip`:

```
has_attached_file :qrcode_png
has_attached_file :qrcode_svg
```

When I have been tried to attach the image:

```
label.qrcode_png = generate_qrcode(label.id.to_s)
label.save!
```

and got an exception *Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError*

> No handler found for MiniMagick::Image:0x007fa629e71388
>   @path="/var/folders/fs/yf7s27kj27n3lmdywp4tgcm80000gn/T/mini_magick20120816-2170-1w6vbz.png",
>   @tempfile=#

What's a problem with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I got it. I have to return a file object instead of `MiniMagick::Image`:

```
File.open(image.path)
```

Then `paperclip` can find and read a file from the file system and save it.